# simple merge of CSV file

Tags: csv, merge

I want to merge two CSV without any condition and no primary.It should be first row file1 and file2.

file1

```
id,name,city
```

file2

```
mobileno,address,email
```

output

```
id,name,city,mobileno,address,,email
```

can you please let me know how can i achive this output

Comment: Are we to assume that the double comma in the output is a typo?

Answer (score 5):

Use paste and set the delimiter to comma as opposed to tab with -d:

```
paste -d, file1 file2
```